# ASP.NET MVC 4 and ajax patterns

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm playing with ASP.NET MVC 4 Developer Preview, and I can see they built the template with some ajax, some modal dialogs to login and register for example.  I'm not very familiar with javascript, and I'm afraid I can mess up the code.

I don't know if there's a pattern to create that kind of dialogs, how to interact them with the controllers actions, and so on, and it's very hard at this time to find some good articles, etc, to study it. So, where to start? There are some nice sites, books (I guess it's too early), to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Normally questions like this would just get closed, but instead it feels like you just need some advice.

1. **[Don't be afraid to break it.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/11/dont-be-afraid-to-break-stuff.html)**

   Right now the code works.  You seem like you know where you want to get, or else you just need to decide that first.  When you know where you want to get, make a change that feels like it's in the right direction, and just do it one step at a time, testing after each change.  When something doesn't work like you expected it to, undo the change and try again.
2. **[Only parts of ASP.NET 4 are new.](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes)**

   When you see a version number after a technology, it means that the product came from something else.  If the technology is well designed, changes in version numbers often times don't change the way you used to do things with that technology.  This is because most technologies try to avoid major breaking changes between versions.  In other words, if you can't find an article on how to do something with MVC 4, look and see if there is a way to do it with MVC 3, and if not 3 then 2, etc.  Once you figure out how to do it in an older version, you'll know if a breaking change was introduced because it won't work when compiled with the latest version.

   When this happens, you should check [the list of breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253815) that is published with most libraries when a new version is released, and if you don't find the answer there, try writing an email to the person who wrote the example or asking one of your peers, teachers, stack overflow, etc.  The point is that you tried to get something working first, got stuck and just need help to get you past the next hump, then you ask the question.
3. **Javascript is old as dirt.**

   The real advice here is to break the problem into sub problems.  Javascript is old, and there are tons of ways to create a dialog in with it.  Choose any one that works, then figure out how to wire up a form using ajax, because that's also in javascript.  Only the last part, handling the request is specific to ASP.NET MVC, and then you go right back to the previous advice of finding out how to handle that in older versions.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure specifically about MVC 4, but MVC 3 allows you to return a partial view for an ajax request. This partial view can then be inserted as-is on the client-side into the DOM and you can make the appropriate javascript calls to make that returned HTML an active modal popup. The javascript calls required for the AJAX request and the UI modal depend heavily on what, if any, javascript framework you are using. jQuery framework has several methods to initiate and handle an AJAX call. jQuery UI, Twitter Bootstrap JS, and many other UI frameworks have "widgets" or methods to create and show a modal dialog.